# History expansion with a string containing whitespace

Tags: terminal, autocomplete, history

I've been using unix for awhile and haven't like to use `!`, which, for as long as I've used unix, I've interpreted as find the last command that begins with the string following `!`, but it seems to not be doing what I am expecting on this new server I am using.

The last command that I executed was `git commit --amend --no-edit`.

When I use `!git` it does as I expected, i.e., executes `git commit --amend --no-edit`. But why is it when I do `!git commit`, it tries to append `commit` to `git commit --amend --no-edit`? Does it only recognize the string prior to the space, which in this case is just `git`, and everything after the space gets appended to the most recent command beginning with `git`? If so, is it possible to change the default behavior to searching for the most recent command that begins with `git commit`?

```
[my_server] !git
git commit --amend --no-edit
[packed_params 351431e14c] draft
 Date: Mon Feb 28 07:51:56 2022 -0800
 4 files changed, 274 insertions(+), 47 deletions(-)
 ...
[my_server] !git commit
git commit --amend --no-edit commit
error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Comment: You can use `!?git commit`. However, it will find the last command **containing**, not necessarily **start with** `git commit`

Comment: @pLumo Ah I see. Is this system-dependent or is it uniform across all unix? Could've sworn `!git commit` worked on other servers, but I could have misremembered

Comment: @anonuser01, history expansion is a shell feature, it depends on the shell how it works, or if you even have it. Though as far as I tested, all of Bash, zsh and tcsh treat `!echo bar` as finding the last `echo` command line and adding `bar` at the end. Bash's documentation for history expansion is here, in case that's the shell you use: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html (I think the feature is originally from csh(?) but I'd expect such a basic detail would have copied consistently to others.)